# ng-repeat doesn't work if i include class="sidebar-menu" inside <ul> in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, sidebar

This is very strange as it shouldn't happen. The moment I include class="sidebar-menu" inside  tag, the ng-repeat inside it, doesn't work at all. I have a list, among which, in one of the list item, when i click I am fetching data from a file "database.json", but when i try to give the sidebar look to the list items by including class "sidebar-menu" in  tag, the ng-repeat stops working.

Here is my code :

```
<!-- Sidebar Menu -->
<div ng-controller="people">
  <ul class="sidebar-menu"> 
    <li class="header">HEADER</li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Link</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Another Link</span></a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i>
        <span ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">Multilevel
          <div ng-show="showDiv">
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
              <li ng-repeat="person in persons">
                {{ person.Name }}<a href="#"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
```

The Controller.js file : This is the controller part and i have included this file in the above code.

```
    var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
    app.controller('people',function($scope,$http){
        $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/database.json')
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.persons = response.records;

    });
    });
```

database.json file : I am displaying these records when i click on "Multilevel" list item from the Menu bar.

```
    {
        "records":[
            {
                "Name" : "Alex",
                "Age" : 24
            },
            {
                "Name" : "Lexi",
                "Age" : 28
            },
            {
                "Name" : "Dex",
                "Age" :25
            },
            {
                "Name" : "Debra",
                "Age" : 26
            }

        ]
    }
```

Comment: post your persons array

Comment: did you get any errors in console

Comment: any leads yet ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
      <li class="header">HEADER</li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Link</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Another Link</span></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            <span ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">Multilevel
            <div ng-show="showDiv">
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li ng-repeat="person in persons">
                   {{ person.Name }} 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </span>
  </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here is the working [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/AOGXn3mcg0nW0zd6Q0pe?p=preview)

Comment: It is still not working for me. Just a question, in your DEMO, i couldn't find anything in style.css, had you added anything in it?

Comment: @BhumikaPandey its working in the demo, no i have not added any css

Comment: Yep, in demo i can see it working. but when i am doing the same thing in my code, it is not working.  But ya as i said earlier, if i remove class="sidebar-menu" from ul, it works, but then the sidebar look goes off. instead it comes as a normal list.

Comment: post the css here, i can apply and see

Comment: I have not written any css for this, but i can paste here the whole file :

Comment: i need the css files too, add me on skype :sajee4ever

Comment: give me your skype email id

Comment: skypid : sajee4ever

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="people">
        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li class="header">HEADER</li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Link</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Another Link</span></a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
                    <div ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">
                        Multilevel
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div ng-show="showDiv">
                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                        <li ng-repeat="person in persons">
                            <a href="">{{person.Name}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```